# Remove space between app border and a List view

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm developing an android app which uses a list view using android studio.But when i use it a space is being displayed between list view and app borders.how can i remove that space?? Like in this pic I need my app to be designed .The following code is XML code for listview i got in  my editor.Suggest the changes for space removal.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The link you are posting is broke.  You should also post some code of your XML layouts.

Comment: There is most likely a padding in the root layout (such as FrameLayout). But please post your XML layout.

Comment: <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />  The above XML code for listview

Comment: Simply, remove `android:paddingXYZ` from your RelativeLayout

Comment: Thanx   @DerGolem It was solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The padding is due to the padding provided to `RelativeLayout`

From your XML code remove padding by making you code look like

```
<RelativeLayout     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"     
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```